# krajee bootstrap-fileinput uploadExtraData cant return data-nnn from the input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, file-io

I try to get the data-filetype, from the input type file used to send the file to the server.

I set my input like :

```
<label class="control-label">My file</label>
<input id="filetype-3" name="filetype_3" type="file" class="file" data-filetype="3">
```

and I try use uploadExtraData ([doc description](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#option-uploadextradata)) like this :

```
uploadExtraData: function() {
    return {
        userid: $("#id").val(),
        filetype: $(this).closest("input[name='t']").data('filetype'),
        tfile: 'ufile'
    };
}
```

But when the upload button is fired,  $(this).closest("input[name='t']").data('filetype') is always, and definitely undefined.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found how do the trick :

```
uploadExtraData: function() {
    var self = this, $el = self.$element, $cont, t, tmp;
    inputid = $el.attr('id');
    formid = $el.closest("form").attr('id');
    return {
        id: $("#id").val(),
        filetype: inputid,
        form: formid,
        t: 'userfile'
    };
}
```